# Meaning of "#" in folder details Windows 7

Tags: windows

On Windows 7 when I look at the details of files in a folder I see a column titled simply "#".  I can see this when I open Windows Explorer, Alt-V, Choose Details.
What is this column?
[image]

Comment: I ALWAYS thought it was a track number

Answer (score 0):

It's just a predefined name for a possible property to be associated with some
particular file type. If there's no Property Handler registered in Windows that
provides a value for the "#" property, as might be done by some program that handles
a proprietary file type/extension that has a "#" property, then the "#" column will
 always be blank.

That said, the "#" symbol is generally interpreted to mean "number".

Comment: Is there a generic way finding out the handler etc for each of the properties listed in there?

Comment: When I choose properties from context menu and click on details tab it does give me an opportunity to change it.  It shows up  in the Media section.  And I see it only for .mp3 files, so track number seems a meaningful fit.

Comment: Your comment jogged my memory. I too have the column. It is available to add in any folder, but I believe I have seen it set to the track number attribute of media files.